# MVC5 ViewModel properties null on HTTPPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post, model-binding

I know, this question has been asked before, but I haven't found an answer yet and my example seems much simpler than most.  I make sure the model data is inside the form and I made sure the Post action matches the Get action; there are no date formatting issues; and I have similar views & controllers that work fine which I've compared to.  This example uses conventional routing, but I've tried attribute routing as well, with no change in behavior.  I have even removed the EditorFor ReportName and put it in a HiddenFor instead.  The Hidden ReportID is always populated and correct, the ReportName and ReportAbbr are always null. :(

First, here is my viewmodel:

```
namespace Core.AdminData
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(Name = "MyReport")]
    public class MyReport
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "ReportID", Order = 0)]
        public int ReportID { get; set; }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "ReportName", Order = 1)]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required")]
        public string ReportName { get; private set; }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name = "ReportAbbr", Order = 2)]
        [Display(Name = "Abbreviation")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Abbreviation Required")]
        public string ReportAbbr { get; private set; }

        public MyReport()
        {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TrendEdit(int id)
    {
        using (Client client = new Client(ConfigHelper.Protocol(), ConfigHelper.Host(), ConfigHelper.Port()))
        {
            MyReport rpt = null;
            try
            {
                rpt = client.GetReport(id);
                if (rpt == null)
                {
                    TempData["ErrorText"] = "Report does not exist";
                    return this.RedirectToAction("List");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                TempData["ErrorText"] = exc.Message;
                return this.RedirectToAction("List");
            }
            return View(rpt);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TrendEdit(MyReport report)
    {
        using (Client client = new Client(ConfigHelper.Protocol(), ConfigHelper.Host(), ConfigHelper.Port()))
        {
            try
            {
                if (!this.ModelState.IsValid || client.UpdateReport(report).StatusCode != SSStatus.Success)
                {
                    ViewBag.ErrorText = "An error occurred.  Please contact your web administrator for assistance.";
                    return View(report);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorText = exc.Message;
                return View(report);
            }
            return this.RedirectToAction("List");
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here is my view:

```
@using Core.AdminData
@model MyReport

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Report";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ContentLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading hidden-xs">
        <h4>Edit Report</h4>
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportID)

        <div class="container-fluid panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 message-error">@ViewBag.ErrorText</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 custom-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportName)
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9 custom-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportName)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-9 message-error">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReportName)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 custom-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportAbbr)
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9 custom-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportAbbr)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-9 message-error">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReportAbbr)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 text-right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

If I've missed any code that would be helpful, please let me know.  I hope this is something obvious.  I'd rather have a "Duh" moment than to keep fighting with this code. ;)  TIA!

Comment: One other note in case it helps, the data for ReportName and ReportAbbr ~are~ in the Request.Form.  It's only the report.ReportName in the TrendEdit post that is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ReportName` and `ReportAbbr` properties have private setters, so the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set the value. Change them to have public setters

```
public string ReportName { get; set; }
public string ReportAbbr { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen!  Just as I had hoped - duh! The class was created by someone who left the company months ago and I just took over.  I kept looking at the attributes, thinking some meta-data must be wrong and completely missed seeing the private setters.  Thank you so much!